# Writing SQL in VBA to obtain the record source which is equal to current ford

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

this is my first time posting, so I am hoping I give all the details I need to.

I am trying to get select a record sorce which is equal to the record which is currently displayed on the form to import data into Word using the bookmark function. I've got the word part to work, what I can't seem to fathom is the SQL in VBA. I spent a good couple of hours researching this and I know the SQL taken directly wont work, but I can't seem to work out what it needs to be changed to and after looking through other posts and implementing the changes others had suggested in other circumstances.

My SQL is:

```
    SELECT TblJob.JobID, TblJob.JobTitle, TblJob.Location, TblJob.ScreeningQ1, TblJob.ScreeningQ2, TblJob.ScreeningQ3, TblJob.ScreeningQ4, TblJob.ScreeningQ5, TblJob.ScreeningQ6, TblJob.ScreeningQ7, TblJob.ScreeningQ8, TblJob.ScreeningQ9, TblJob.ScreenignQ10
    FROM TblJob
    WHERE (((TblJob.JobID)=[Forms]![FrmJob]![JobID]));
```

The code I was trying to implement was:

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, strsql, val As String
    val = Forms!FrmJob!JobID
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM TblJob WHERE JobID = '" & val & "'"
```

Any help any one can offer would get greatly appreciated, I am still very much a beginner when it comes to coding and the posts on this site has been fantastic on helping me so far!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this our, if the answer can help anyone else

```
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM TblJob WHERE JobID=" & Me.JobID
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Here is a code of my script using ADODB library in Excel.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};" & "DBQ=" & Database_Name & ";UID=" & 
User_ID & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
strsql = "some_sql"
rs.Open SQLStr, cn
'Sheets(dane_wymag).Cells(knc + 1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```